# Converting Shape Files to TopoJSON using the TopoJSON 2.0 API

Tags: node.js, d3.js, shapefile, topojson

I'm trying to create an app that will allow you to interact with any of the zip codes in any of the US states. I'm accomplishing this by using topoJSON and d3 to draw maps. I've had a lot of trouble finding a topojson file that has all the data that I need, so I've used GQIS to create my own shapefiles of the US states.

The last step I have is converting the shape file I create into a topoJSON file. I've watched some tutorials that used the old version of the topoJSON command line, and they were able to transform their shapefiles into topojson files by simply running a command like this:

```
topojson -p -o illinois.zcta.json -- illinois.shp
```

My understanding is the anatomy of that request is:

```
topojson (invoking node module) -p(all properties) -o(all objects) illinois.zcta.json(name of file you want) -- illinois.shp(name of file to converT)
```

However, the Topojson API appears to have been updated and no longer supports this request. I've installed topojson globally using NPM and trying to run the function above alerts me that topoJSON is not a function.

I've dug into [the documentation](https://github.com/topojson/topojson) surrounding the new version of the topoJSON command line and it appears to be much more complicated. There are a ton more ways to slice up data - but none of them appear to take a Shapefile and convert it to Topojson, or take a shape file and convert it to geoJSON which I could then change into Topojson. It seems odd to me that this functionality (changing a .shp file directly into a topojson file) would be removed - although the fact that it could is magical in the first place. Can anyone direct me as to the best way to convert shape files into topojson files? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a sequence of `shp2json` (https://github.com/substack/shp2json) and `geo2topo` (https://github.com/topojson/topojson-server/blob/master/README.md#geo2topo). But you can also get geojson straight from QGIS in which case you can skip the first step.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get a working GeoJSON file using shp2json, but when I attempt to convert it with geo2topo I'm encountering errors in the JSON itself that lead to both files emptying out? I'm going to try exporting the geoJSON from QGIS directly and see if that goes smoother with geo2topo.